What is the scriptural reference of Svarnamukhi, Sonebhadra and Sphatik shilas?
We all have seen references to Banalinga and Shaligram in the Puranas but there are 3 more swayambhu shilas Svarnamukhi(for Shakti), Sonebhadra(for Ganapati) and Sphatik(for Suryanarayan) used in panchayatana puja. Can anyone please give what is the scriptural reference of the other three shilas?
